# Rally Rest API....add defect to defect suite

Tags: rally, defects

I've done some research on this topic, but haven't found anything useful.

I need to add an existing defect to an existing defect suite using the Rally rest API.

Does anybody know how to do this?  I've tried a number of things, none of which work.

Any tips, suggestions, pointers would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance, Brian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a browser's REST client please try to POST:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defectsuite/22222/defects/add?key=abc123...
```

using this request body:

```
{
    "CollectionItems": [
    {"_ref": "/defect/3333"}
]
}
```

For more info on how v2.0 deals with collections please see Collection section in [WS API documentation.](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/)

Also, notice that authorization key needs to be generated first:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/security/authorize
```

You will GET back a string

```
{"OperationResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": [], "Warnings": [], "SecurityToken": "abc123..."}}
```

Comment: somebody get the man a coffee.  It worked.  Thanks for your help!